# bower not adding all bower_component css files to index

Tags: html, css, gruntjs, bower, yeoman

So I have this `Yeoman angular fullstack MEAN` project where I have added the `material design icons` to my `bower_components`. however this is not automaticly added to my `index.html` page like all my other `.css` files.

Is there a way to make this happen, because at the moment whenever I start my project I have to add the reference to the `.css` file manually.

my index.html looks like this

```
<head>
    ...

    <!-- build:css(client) app/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,client}) app/app.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/app.css">
    <!-- injector:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/account/login/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/admin/admin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/impression/impression.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/information/information.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/main/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/shop/shop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/turnament/turnament.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/modal/modal.css">
    <!-- endinjector -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
```

I whould like it to look like this

```
<head>
    ...

    <!-- build:css(client) app/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->

    ...
</head>
```

**EDIT**

bower_component/mdi/bower.json

```
{
    "name": "mdi",
    "version": "1.1.70",
    "main": [
        "css/materialdesignicons.css",
        "fonts/*",
        "css/*",
        "scss/*",
        "package.json",
        "preview.html"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://materialdesignicons.com",
    "authors": [
        { "name": "Austin Andrews", "homepage": "http://templarian.com" },
        { "name": "Google", "homepage": "http://www.google.com/design" }
    ],
    "license": ["OFL-1.1", "MIT"],
    "ignore": [
        "*.md",
        "*.json"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "material",
        "design",
        "icons",
        "webfont"
    ]
}
```

/bower.json

```
{
    "name": "lunorth",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": ">=1.2.*",
        "json3": "~3.3.1",
        "es5-shim": "~3.0.1",
        "jquery": "~1.11.0",
        "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
        "angular-resource": ">=1.2.*",
        "angular-cookies": ">=1.2.*",
        "angular-sanitize": ">=1.2.*",
        "angular-route": ">=1.2.*",
        "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
        "font-awesome": ">=4.1.0",
        "lodash": "~2.4.1",
        "angular-socket-io": "~0.6.0",
        "angular-animate": "~1.4.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": ">=1.2.*",
        "angular-scenario": ">=1.2.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the missing bower package bower.json files, sometimes they won't get added if there isn't a 'main' property listed which is the file or array of files that will be added by wiredep

Comment: @tenderloin: I just added my bower.json file from my mdi folder, and it has a `main`. Is that the one you where mentioning?

Comment: Yes that's the one, the only other thing I can think of is that when you installed the package via Bower you didn't save it as a dependency with '--save'. Can you check you projects bower.json to confirm?

Comment: I think that was your problem, add "mdi" and the version under dependencies and rebuild your project

Comment: @tenderloin: that fixed it. can you make an answer so that I can close this one?

Comment: That's good news :) I will post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing Material Design Icons from the list of dependencies in your projects `bower.json` file.

If you add the name and version to your dependencies it will fix your issue.

```
"dependencies": {
        "mdi": "1.1.70",
        ...,
        ...
}
```

If you installed the package via the command line you can use `--save` to add it to your project dependencies.

Another common problem with wiredep is the missing package's `bower.json` file is missing the 'main' property.